# Enable/Disable Auto Refresh with a Button

Tags: javascript, html

I have recently made a webpage that needs to refresh every few seconds, but in some cases; navigation or other things may be interrupted by the constant refreshing.

I am seeking a way to enable/disable the auto-refresh preferably using JavaScript.

This way, I can click a button on my webpage to have auto-refreshing set to on and another button to turn it off.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use ajax?

Comment: Don't know how, and quite frankly; too complicated for something like this. @FastSnail

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As *@FastSnail* mentioned you should be using Ajax for this.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek How would I do it in AJAX?

Comment: Read through some Ajax tutorials, or if you can you could use jQuery's [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which is a bit more simplistic compared to naively doing it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see [ask] in the Help Center and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off using AJAX and jQuery for this. It's actually **very** simple.

```
  setInterval(function(){
   $('#my_div').load('/path/to/server/source');
   }, 2000)
```

This would re-load the div with the ID "my_div" every two seconds and refresh it with the specified path. `.load()` is short for `$.ajax`.